# Does Visual Studio Code always debug C# code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm starting to program in C# and decided to install Visual Studio Code as my text editor and installed the extension called C# Dev Kit. When running the code (without debugging) with the following button:

https://learn-attachment.microsoft.com/api/attachments/c8dad1ae-b55b-4c70-a3bb-f35e4c869c67?platform=QnA

I noticed that the following command was being executed in the Visual Studio Code terminal:

https://learn-attachment.microsoft.com/api/attachments/df4f1fe9-da30-4dca-b32b-804665e8df85?platform=QnA

**Command: PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Calculadora> & 'c:\Users\User.vscode\extensions\ms-dotnettools.csharp-2.22.5-win32-x64.debugger\x86_64\vsdbg.exe' '--interpreter=vscode' '--connection=2f353c5843504a368c832105e58f278a'**

Apparently, this command is running a debugger called vsdbg.exe located in the C# extension folder. My question is why does this happen if I'm only running my code and not debugging it? Shouldn't It be running a command like "dotnet run" or something similar to just run it and not debug it? When running the code with the debug button, which is the following:

https://learn-attachment.microsoft.com/api/attachments/05605d3f-866e-4429-833a-4e06821169b1?platform=QnA

I noticed that it executed exactly the same command.

I have tried with other languages like C or C++, and it also seems that they always debug even when you're just running them without debugging.

I'm just trying to understand how this works and if It always debug my code.